# Why is JavaScript's "use strict" not a magic comment?

Tags: javascript, strict

Every other language I've used, does something akin to magic comments when you want to change compiler/interpreter level things:

e.g. in C, you use the preprocessor:

```
#pragma GCC dependency "parse.y"
```

In Ruby, a comment:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

In Haskell, a comment:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface, CPP #-}
```

In *nix scripts, a comment:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

But in JavaScript, [a String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode). Like actual program data. This seems pretty crazy to me, does the interpreter create the string literal and then check its value? Or is this particular string never instantiated (or w/e the equivlaent is in JS) And why a String? It's so atypical and illogical (since it's program data, not metadata) that I was very sure my friend was pulling my leg me when he told me this.

```
"use strict";
```

Comment: If there is something specific about the specification that confuses you, then could you cite which part of the specification confuses you and your specific confusion? For reference, it's here: http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Annex_C

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that the questions posed are: (1) Why is JavaScript's “use strict” not a magic comment? (from the title), (2) Does the interpreter create the string literal and then check its value? (from the body, i.e. how is this implemented), and (3) Why a String? (from the body, i.e. what motivated this design choice).

Comment: Voted to reopen as I'm pretty curious. There is presumably one or more specific, objective reasons for this decision. Presumably JavaScript could have used `/* use strict */` or `/* __STRICT__ */` or the like in place of `"use strict";`.

Comment: Actually, a little bit of thought and I have the answer. JavaScript, unlike C or Ruby or Haskel, is almost always minified and concatenated in production. Typically comments are stripped out, meaning that `/* use strict */` would never make it to the browser. Making `use strict` a comment would break all existing JavaScript minification engines until they had time to be updated.

Comment: firefox used to throw out comments when it parsed a function, including the time around when strict surfaced. i think an ecmaScript engine doesn't need to keep comments per the spec, so that would be a deal-breaker for any kind of special comment.

Comment: That's a good point, @meagar, I'd bet that's why, though would be nice to get a reference.

Comment: @dandavis: an implementation doesn't need to keep string literals that have no side effects either -- in both cases the JavaScript engine will need to be changed to allow for the interpretation of the `"use strict"` pragma.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's a great point, too, @Qantas94Heavy, I think compilers typically optimize things like that away.

Comment: @dandavis Yes, this isn't really relevant. The JS engine needs to be changed to implement the whole of strict mode, and if it were decided that strict mode would be turned on a magic comment, then JS engines would have one more (comparatively small) change to make in implementing strict mode.

Comment: Also, since strict mode was a late addition to Javascript, going with a string literal is less likely to cause backwards compatibility problems. It's easy to imagine that someone may have the *comment* `/* use strict */` in their code without intending to invoke strict mode; but it's much less likely that they have a string literal `"use strict";` in their code which does nothing.

Comment: checking the spec reveals that it's implemented by checking the first parsed SourceElement for a match, so it's likely defined that way for convenience to the over-all internal Function/program workflow...